# attendance date of my BS and MS course

Tags: graduate-admissions

I have completed my graduation from Bangladesh. And i am applying for graduation study at USA. All of the universities mentioned to write the attendance date  of my BS and MS course. But there are not any official record  with me and even in my certificate. But  i can see in my certificate "publish date of results" and session mentioned. The university where I studied took  6 years to complete 4 years course.  Now what date will I write there?

Will I write what I assumed ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should write the date you started and the date you finish. It's OK that this cannot be certified by your university "officially". Your official transcript should show the dates of the courses your took along with their names and the grades your got.

Comment: I do  not remember all of the dates but months. Even the university  doesn't have the precise course ending date.

Comment: @UnlimitedDreamer: Normally months are sufficient (just as they would be on a CV or resumé).